# Example of a Linear Map that is NOT surjective **and** NOT injective

Tags: linear-algebra

I can come up with non-linear such maps e.g. $$y=x^2+5$$

However, is there a linear such map that is not injective nor surjective?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto 0$.

Comment: Sure, there are lost of linear maps that are neither injective nor surjective.  Hint: Consider a linear map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is a line.

Comment: of course, thanks !

Comment: Generally speaking, a map is not surjective when the codomain is too big.  Therefore, if you take any linear map $\mathbb{R}^a\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^b$ and make $b$ too big, then the map is not surjective.  On the other hand, not being injective means that the image is too small, so if the image has dimension smaller than $a$, the map will not be injective.

Comment: But, and that's something very interesting, if you take a linear map between two vector spaces with the same dimension (finite !), injectivity, surjectivity and bijectivity are equivalent. This is not true in infinite dimensional spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the family $\mathcal{F}=\{f_c| f_c:\mathbb {R}\to\mathbb {R}, f_c(x)=c, c\in\mathbb {R}\}$. Every function isn't surjective because the image is only one point, and isn't injective because all real numbers are maping to $c$.

If you want that $f$ be linear, consider $f_0\in\mathcal{F}$

Comment: But they are not linear unless $c=0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $m>n$. Consider $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$ where $V$ is the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$ over $\mathbb{F}$, and $W$ is the space of polynomials of degree $\leq m$ over $\mathbb{F}$. Consider a differentiation map from $V$ to $W$.